# Trying to convert PCM to frequency chart but result looks very strange near 0

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, wav

I tried convert PCM data from wav file and FFT to frequency chart.
Here is my chart.
[image: start from 0.00s]
0.00s 512 sample count
[image: start from 3.15s]
3.15s 512 sample count

The sound file almost quietly and have some knock sound start at 3s.

I noticed near 0 the value very high. But how it can be! 
Another strange point is "the value is 0 when frequency greater than about 16000".

Here is my code:

```
import soundfile as sf
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


_audio_path = 'source_normal.wav'


def plot_data(pcm_data, samplerate, current_time):
    x_axis = np.arange(0, len(pcm_data) - 1) / len(pcm_data) * samplerate
    complex_data = [x+0j for x in pcm_data]
    result = np.fft.fft(complex_data)
    length = len(pcm_data) // 2
    amplitudes = [math.sqrt(x.imag * x.imag + x.real * x.real) for x in result[:length]]
    plt.plot(x_axis[:length], amplitudes)
    plt.title('{}s sample count: {}'.format(current_time, len(pcm_data)))
    plt.xlabel('{}Hz'.format(samplerate))
    plt.show()


def baz():
    data, samplerate = sf.read(_audio_path, dtype='int16')
    window = 512
    total_number_of_data = len(data)
    current_index = 0 # 144000
    while current_index < total_number_of_data:
        d = data[current_index:current_index+window]
        current_time = current_index / samplerate
        print('current time: {}'.format(current_index / samplerate))
        plot_data(d, samplerate, current_time)
        current_index += window


if __name__ == '__main__':
    baz()
```

I not familiar with DSP and never tried before. So I think my code have some mistake, please help, thank you.

here is my sound file [sound file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap94drcu7394oj9Tfua3q4Y45CgE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This high value you see on the first plot is caused by the constant component in the window. Try normalization: shift all window's values by its average.

Tail zeros are just amplitudes small enough to look like zeros. Check out their values to ensure ;)